# do not keep activities option results in crashing my app

Tags: java, android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

User reported, that my App restarts ( main activity ) when a subactivity is started ( started per Button ).
I realized that the following option activated forces this : settings->{}developer options->'Do not keep activities' .

How can I prevent this ? Did I coded something wrong ?

Go-Launcher has the same Problem when opening settings-options in Go-Launcher. Go-Launcher popups a message with the advice to deactivate this setting.

Does anyone know howto read this setting ? I was not able to find the right variable of the class Settings.

regards

Comment: You need to post some code or logs. anything where people could find any mistakes, errors, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a solution from stackoverflow user 'yorkw'. Thanks alot to yorkw !

I check if the option is activated. If so I show a dialog to warn the user.

```
int value = Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.ALWAYS_FINISH_ACTIVITIES, 0);
```

regards

Answer (score 0):

"do not keep activities", it used to simulate hard condition when the system not keeping activities,

mostly it's rare case but you should and need to handle this,

I would advise to you to check the source of the problem  and handle it correct

Comment: Thanks for reply. I try to find the source of the problem.

Comment: Hi All. I am pretty sure, that the problem isn't my code. GO-Launcher has the same problem when opening 'Settings'. Go-Launcher also popups a message to advice to deactivate this setting. Now I tried to find out with code, if this setting is activated, but I dont find the right variable in the class settings. Does anyone know howto to read the setting 'do not keep activities' from the developer-settings.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this issue with a clean simple example:
The fact is, that when the option 'do not keep activities' is checked, then activities will be killed.
For example: A Mainactivity calls a subactivity. The mainactivity is killed. Pressing back on the subactivity results in restarting the Mainactivity. This can be a problem, when the mainactivity is doing longrunning stuffs like loading content.

My conclusion on this. The option 'do not keep activites' is an developer option and should not be set under normal user-conditions.